# Asus TUF F15 FX506HM Trackpad issue

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, 21.04

I am new to Linux and I just installed Ubuntu on a new ASUS TUF F15 FX506HM, and I had a couple of problems regarding the Wi-Fi adapter and the touchpad. In order to solve the Wi-Fi problem I updated the kernel to the latest version, but that did not solve the trackpad issue (did not solve the Wi-Fi problem completely either, apparently there are no drivers yet for the Wi-Fi adapter I have mt7921e, but this is a different discussion for another time).

To solve the trackpad issue I followed a couple of tutorials on YouTube and discussions on different forums and the solutions found were to edit the grub file in /etc/default/grub and to modify the two lines containing "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" and "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" introducing different values for those two fields. No solution worked.

Please help me, I do not know what to do next. This is the output from the xinput command:

```
    WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:17                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:17              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:17                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 with the kernel 5.12.10. Thank you for your help and attention!

Comment: Hey! did you find any solutions? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I did not find any sollutions...

Answer (score -1):

Today, all of a sudden, the touchpad started to work for me under Arch Linux. Try updating your system.

Libinput identifies the touchpad as:

```
Device:           ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event258
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             101x52mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

And XInput identifies it as:

```
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Info about the kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.13.12-arch1-1
```

Comment: [Answers that aren't about Ubuntu (explicitly about another distro)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19206/348964)